# Signature verification failed vert.x

Tags: java, jwt, vert.x

I am trying to add JWT authentication to my vert.x application and this is what I have done so far:
generated keystore with the following command:

> keytool -genseckey -keystore keystore.jceks -storetype jceks
>   -storepass secret -keyalg HMacSHA256 -keysize 2048 -alias HS256 -keypass secret

as it is recommended [here](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-auth-jwt/java/).
Then in my start method I have initialized JWTAuth instance:

```
jwt = JWTAuth.create(vertx, new JsonObject()
                    .put("keyStore", new JsonObject()
                    .put("type", "jceks")
                    .put("path", "keystore.jceks")
                    .put("password", "secret")));
```

And added handler for api route:

```
router.route("/api/create_room")
            .blockingHandler(JWTAuthHandler.create(jwt));
```

Now, when I'm sending a request with some Bearer token in the Authorization header I get:

```
WARNING: JWT decode failure
java.lang.RuntimeException: Signature verification failed
```

I have tested the token [here](https://jwt.io/) and it says that the signature is verified correctly.
Did I do something wrong ? Or is it a bug in a vert.x library ?

**UPD**

```
private static final String DEFAULT_ALGORITHM = "HMACSHA256";
@Override
  public synchronized byte[] sign(byte[] payload) {
    SecretKey sk = new SecretKeySpec("secret".getBytes(), DEFAULT_ALGORITHM);
    try {
        mac.init(sk);
        return mac.doFinal(payload);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

  }
```

I've added sk for testing purposes, obviously. I guess there's a problem during `cryptoMap` initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing means that the parsing of the token as per the [site you linked](http://jwt.io) is correct, however the signature did not match the content of the token.

You are initializing the JWT with your custom signature so you can only verify tokens you have issued yourself. How are you issuing the tokens?

In other words using this mode only tokens created by yourself can be verified.

Comment: The tokens are created with spring-security-jwt. The process basically ends up with                      `Signer signer = new MacSigner(secret);
    Jwt jwt = JwtHelper.encode(content, signer);`                
But I know the secret, which basically means that I can decode the token. I've double checked and made sure that the secret used during signing process of token is the same as when checking the signature in vert.x app.

Comment: the mac is not being initialized, when I modified the `sign` method in `Crypto` class by adding `mac.init(sk);` before signing the verification returned true. I am not that good at those encryption stuff, can you verify my suggestion ?

Comment: What is the `sk` variable? can you share your modified code?

Comment: What are you trying to achive with replacing the private key?

Comment: In order to troubleshoot your issue we need the keystore file + the token that failed to decode, because everything seems to be correct.

Comment: I am not replacing the private key, I am initializing the mac again with the same key. The keystore file is generated with the command given above, nothing else. I have tried different tokens, eg. those that are used in my app and newly created with, for example, [this site](http://jwtbuilder.jamiekurtz.com/). Btw, when I downloaded version 3.5.0-SNAPSHOT and tried to run unit tests for mac verification - they fail.